# Deploying Flask application with Apache2 Proxy Server

Tags: python, flask, proxy, apache2, gunicorn

I'm trying to deploy a Flask application with Gunicorn with a Proxy Server in Apache2. The Flask application is running in a Docker container but not the Apache2 server.

Here is the configuration for Apache2.

```
<Macro DemoSubdomain $subdomain_name $proxy_pass_proto $proxy_pass_to>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName $subdomain_name.example.com

    ProxyPass / $proxy_pass_proto://$proxy_pass_to
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} upgrade [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) "ws://$proxy_pass_to/$1" [P,L]

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile      /root/example.com-crt.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   /root/example.com-key.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /root/example.com-chain.pem
</VirtualHost>
</Macro>
```

The Flask application runs in the 'subdomain_name.example.com' when 'SERVER_NAME' is not specified in Config, however when calling redirect function, it redirects to `localhost:17000`.

So, in Flask application, I set the `config['SERVER_NAME']` to 'subdomain_name.example.com' and run Gunicorn. But, I am getting the following error.

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py:1777: UserWarning: Current server name 'localhost:17000' doesn't match configured server name 'subdomain_name.example.com'
app_1    |   return self.url_map.bind_to_environ(
app_1    | ERROR:some_app.app.app:Exception on / [GET]
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to setup a simple website with https, I can offer the steps I've taken.

**Assumptions:**

- Server is a "New `Ubuntu` Image" (ie. on a Raspberry Pi)
- You have a Python Flask app
- You want the server to host https traffic
- You own a domain name (ie. example.com)

---

## Step 0.

- Configure the server to allow SSH traffic

```
# Tell Universal Firewall (ufw) to Allow SSH connections (on the server)
sudo ufw allow 22
sudo apt update
sudo reboot
```

---

## Step 1.

- Launch Flask App (and expose its port over Public IP)

```
# Connect to the server using SSH
ssh ubuntu@servers.public.ip.addr
# Create some directories
mkdir repos/
mkdir downloads/
mkdir -p secrets/example/
# Install Python3
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
# Install Virtualenv to avoid overlapping dependencies between different python scripts
sudo apt-get install python3-virtualenv
# Create a virtual environment
virtualenv .venv/
# Enter the virtual environment
. .venv/bin/activate
# type 'deactivate' to exit the virtual environment
####################################################
#####   TESTING FIREWALL/CONFIGURING PORTS   #######
####################################################
cd repos
# Run any app to debug your firewall's effect on Ports & Public IP Address
git clone https://github.com/org-not-included/simple_flask_app
cd simple_flask_app
# Install requirements
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
# Run script in background, and write terminal output to logs
python3 main.py &> server_run_details.log & disown
# type 'cat server_run_details.log' to see the logs
# Tell ufw to Allow connections on port 4020 
sudo ufw allow 4020
```

#### Testing Port via Local IP

```
curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:4020
# If your server has a built-in GUI/Desktop View, in a browser you can visit:
http://127.0.0.1:4020
```

#### Testing Port via [Public IP](https://superuser.com/a/949429):

- skip to bottom of file (shift+g)
- update '127.0.0.1' -> '0.0.0.0' (i)
- save and quit (esc :wq! enter)

```
sudo vi main.py
sudo fuser -k 4020/tcp
python3 main.py &> server_run_details.log & disown
# Try hitting the public IP in a terminal
curl -X GET http://servers.public.ip.addr:4020
# Or visit the website in a browser
http://servers.public.ip.addr:4020
# Congrats your Firewall works
```

---

---

## Congrats, you've confirmed your server is able to serve http traffic (via `http://[Public IP]:[Port]`)

---

## Step 2.

- Setup a domain name, so users can visit (http://)`www.example.com` instead of `http://servers.public.ip.addr:4020`.

---

Step 2A:

- Tell DNS Provider to which IP Address hosts the (sub)domain

```
####################################################
####  CONFIGURING A DOMAIN NAME  (example.com)  ####
####################################################
# Tell your Domain Management Provider (porkbun.com, godaddy.com, etc) to point your domain name at your Public IP:
# - visit your Domain Management Provider
# - update the A Record's ANSWER to your Public IP
# - delete the CNAME Record
####################################################
```

---

Step 2B:

- Setup apache2 to redirect traffic for (sub)domain to the appropriate port

```
# Tell ufw to Allow traffic over http (ie. port 80)
sudo ufw allow http
sudo apt update
# Install apache2
# apache2 allows your server to map the domain name to a (flask app) process running on http://localhost:[port]
sudo apt install apache2
# Remove everything from the default configuration and add your mapping for http traffic
### <VirtualHost *:80>
###         ServerName example.com
###         ServerAlias www.example.com
###         ProxyRequests Off
###         ProxyPreserveHost On
###         ProxyPass / http://localhost:4020/
###         ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:4020/
### </VirtualHost>
sudo vi /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf 
# Install apache2 dependencies 
sudo a2enmod proxy
sudo a2enmod proxy_http
sudo a2enmod proxy_ajp
sudo a2enmod proxy_balancer
sudo a2enmod proxy_connect
sudo a2enmod proxy_html
sudo a2enmod ssl
# Tell apache2 to stop running 
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
# Tell apache2 to start running 
sudo a2ensite 000-default.conf
# Have the system manager restart apache2
sudo systemctl reload apache2
# Check the server logs
sudo systemctl status apache2.service
```

---

Step 2C:

- Testing & Troubleshooting

```
Visit your domain in web browser:
- example.com 
- www.example.com
- http://www.example.com

# Is Apache2 is running okay?
sudo systemctl status apache2.service
# If not
## Edit Apache2 Config
sudo vi /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf 
## Restart apache2
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
sudo a2ensite 000-default.conf
sudo systemctl reload apache2

# Is Apache2 is running okay?
sudo systemctl status apache2.service
# If not, go to Step 2C (insert recursion joke here)

# Is your app running okay?
curl -X GET http://example.com/

# Does http work in the web browser?
http://example.com
```

## Congrats, you've confirmed your server is able to serve http traffic (via `http://example.com`)!

---

## Step 3.

- Download an **SSH Bundle** from your **Domain Management Provider**.

---

## Step 4.

- Copy SSH Bundle's files to your server

```
scp -r /local/directory/ ubuntu@my.public.ip.address:/home/ubuntu/secrets/example/
```

---

## Step 5.

- Update your apache2 config to use https traffic instead of http:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /home/ubuntu/secrets/example/domain.cert.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/ubuntu/secrets/example/private.key.pem
        SSLCertificateChainFile /home/ubuntu/secrets/example/intermediate.cert.pem
        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://localhost: 4020
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost: 4020/
</VirtualHost>
```

```
sudo vi /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
# Restart Apache2
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
sudo a2ensite 000-default.conf
sudo systemctl reload apache2
# Is Apache2 is running okay?
sudo systemctl status apache2.service
# Are you able to visit the SSL version in browser?
https://www.example.com
```

---

---

## Congrats, you've confirmed your server is able to serve https traffic (via `https://example.com`)!

---

## Step 6.

- Cleanup

---

### Kill the Simple Flask App:

```
sudo fuser -k 4020/tcp
```

### Remove the example Repo:

```
cd ..
rm -rf simple_flask_app
```

### Delete example from apache2 config

```
sudo vi /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```